# In inspector, class name identifies element but does not appear in 'Rules'

Tags: html, css, razor, visual-studio-2013, less

I'm trying to add a class to an HTML page via less file. When I build (both .less and .cshtml) and open the page in an inspector, the class name does appear, to identify the element, but does not appear anywhere in 'rules'. Why?

I have triple-checked that my CSS is syntactically correct. It looks roughly like this:

```
.broader-class 
{
    .blah-variant;
    properties: values;

    &.narrow
    {
        min-width: 40px;
    }
}
```

That said, I'm concerned I've made a semantic error. I'm working with a larger body of code than what I've created, and I'm new to CSS. '.narrow' is the class I'm trying to apply that is not appearing at all in 'rules' on the inspector, to be clear. '.broader-class' was created before me.

Also possibly relevant: using Visual Studio 2013 and the Razor view engine.